# Comparing avro datatypes in AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I have 2 files with AVRO datatypes (one SQL server data and other one from Redshift) in AWS S3. How do I compare and find out the difference? Is Athena the only way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's mostly irrelevant which database platform this data is sourced from, since neither of those platforms exports data natively to Avro format so we have to assume some third party process has been used to extract the data and generate the files.

To your actual question, which is how to analyse the data in these files and make some kind of comparison, there are a number of options using AWS depending on what you have access to:

1) Copy (load) both files into Redshift and use SQL statements to compare
2) Create Redshift Spectrum tables over the files in S3 and use SQL
3) Create an EMR cluster and use SparkSQL, Presto or another tool running on the cluster to analyse the data
4) Create tables in Athena that reference these files and use SQL

Comment: Thanks a lot. We have decided to create tables in Athena that reference these files and use SQL. we have around 59 tables and this approach seems to take longer time for comparison. Is there any efficient way of comparing programmatically?

Comment: You'll need to provide a lot more information about the type of data in the files, how large they are, what you mean by "compare" and what kind of timeframe you are expecting this to run in.